# issues with IMAP functions php

Tags: php, imap

I am facing some problem with imap function. Basically What I need to do is to read unseen mails. There will be a url in all the mails, i should fetch that URL and store.

```
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password);
if($inbox)//if **1
{
/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'UNSEEN');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) //if **2
{
    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    $varients=array("1","1.1","1.2","2");

    foreach($emails as $email_number) //for loop **1
    {
        $ids [] = $email_number;

        foreach($varients as $cur_varient) //for loop **2
        {
            echo "\n\nstarting with imap function number ". $cur_varient."\n\n";

            $overview     = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);//all varients of like subject, date etc.
            $from         = addslashes(trim($overview[0]->from));
            $inboxed_time = addslashes(trim(strtotime($overview[0]->date)));
            $message      = (imap_body($inbox,$email_number,$cur_varient));

            print addslashes(trim($overview[0]->subject));break;
            preg_match_all('#\bhttp?://[^,\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^,[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $message, $match);

            $link_matched = $match[0];                  
            $input        = 'unsubscribe.php';
            $linkexists   = false;

            foreach($link_matched as $curlink) 
            {                   
                if(stripos($curlink, $input) !== false) 
                {
                $linkexists = true;
                $unsublink  = $curlink;

                $unsublink  = str_replace('href="', '', $unsublink);
                $unsublink  = str_replace('"', '', $unsublink);

                break;
                }
            }



            if(isset($unsublink))
            {   
                $unsublink = addslashes(trim(($unsublink)));
                $thread    = 1;
                $time      = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                $iQry      = " INSERT INTO `SPAMS`.url_queue VALUES(";
                    $iQry     .= " 'default','".$unsublink."','".$thread."','";
                $iQry     .= "".$from."','".$inboxed_time."',UNIX_TIMESTAMP('".$time."'))";

                //mysql_query($iQry);
                print $iQry;
            }
        }//closing for loop **2

    }//closing for loop **1

} //closing if **2

// Setting flag from un-seen email to seen on emails ID.
if(isset($ids))
{
    imap_setflag_full($inbox,implode(",", $ids), "\\Seen \\Flagged"); //IMPORTANT
}

// colse the connection
imap_expunge($inbox);
imap_close($inbox);
}//closing if **1
```

I have used all different varients of imap to make sure it will read different types of mails. Now issue is, sometime the URL matched is broken. Only half URL will be fetched(I printed the entire message, saw that half URL is coming to next line). The other issue is, sometimes, the body fetched will not be the one which the current mail contains. It fetched some other mail content.

I am puzzled what to do, so putting my entire code, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a regex modifiers to match multiline texts too, or you can strip newlines and such from the body of the emails.

```
preg_match("/{pattern}/mi",'Testing'); 
//m for multiline matches and i for case-insensitive matches
```

Your second issue is a bit different than you'd think, emails have multiple bodies, one for simple texts, one for html, some for attachments (and their order is different in apple products).
https://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-message-parts/

You are probably facing the issue of grabbing the wrong one. My recommendation would be to fetch all of the email bodies, like this:

```
$overview = imap_fetch_overview($this->connection, $email_number, 0);
$structure = imap_fetchstructure($this->connection, $email_number);
$message = "";
//$parts = [1, 1.1, 1.2, 2];
if (!$structure->parts)//simple email
    $message .= "Simple: ". imap_fetchbody($this->connection, $email_number, 0). "<br/>";
else {
    foreach ($structure->parts as $partNumber=>$part){
            if ($partNumber != 0)
                $message .= "Part ".$partNumber.": ". imap_fetchbody($this->connection, $email_number, $partNumber)."<br/>";
        }
}
```